# React Native - State doesn't update even with 'onChange' function set

Tags: javascript, react-native

So I have this code here. I don't know if it's cause of how I structured it, but the state changes using the 'set' function doesn't change the state till after I change the entry again. So for example, I'll put in text then I push "post" which should update the state, when console.warn prints it doesn't print anything. Then I change the text again and push post and console.warn will output what was there before my most recent change.

```
import React, {useState, createRef} from 'react';
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  View,
  Text,
  ScrollView,
  Keyboard,
  Button,
  TouchableOpacity,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
} from 'react-native';
import DateTimePickerModal from 'react-native-modal-datetime-picker';
import Loader from '../components/Loader';

const GoalRegistrationScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  const [isDatePickerVisible, setDatePickerVisibility] = useState(false);
  const [goalText, setGoal] = useState('');
  const [durationText, setDuration] = useState('');
  const [descriptionText, setDescription] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [errortext, setErrortext] = useState('');
  const durationInputRef = createRef();
  const descriptionInputRef = createRef();

  function showDatePicker() {
    setDatePickerVisibility(true);
  }

  function hideDatePicker() {
    setDatePickerVisibility(false);
  }

  function handleConfirm(date) {
    hideDatePicker();
    console.warn(date);
  }

  function onButtonClick() {
    // console.warn(goalText)
    console.warn(descriptionText);
  }

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      title: 'Create Goal',
      headerTitleAlign: 'center',
      headerRight: () => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.addButtonStyle}
          activeOpacity={0.5}
          onPress={onButtonClick}>
          <LinearGradient
            colors={['#FBE049', '#4964FB']}
            style={styles.linearGradient}
            start={{x: 0, y: 0}}
            end={{x: 1, y: 1}}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonTextStyle}>Post</Text>
          </LinearGradient>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ),
    });
  }, [navigation]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.mainBody}>
      <Loader loading={loading} />
      <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled">
        <View>
          <KeyboardAvoidingView enabled>
            <View style={styles.SectionStyle}>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.inputStyle}
                onChangeText={goal => setGoal(goal)}
                placeholder="What do I want to accomplish?"
                placeholderTextColor="#8b9cb5"
                autoCapitalize="none"
                returnKeyType="next"
                onSubmitEditing={() =>
                  durationInputRef.current && durationInputRef.current.focus()
                }
                underlineColorAndroid="#f000"
                blurOnSubmit={false}
              />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.SectionStyle}>
              <Button title="Show Date Picker" onPress={showDatePicker} />
              <DateTimePickerModal
                isVisible={isDatePickerVisible}
                mode="date"
                onConfirm={handleConfirm}
                onCancel={hideDatePicker}
                minimumDate={new Date()}
              />
              {/* <TextInput
                style={styles.inputStyle}
                onChangeText={duration => setDuration(duration)}
                placeholder="Duration of Goal"
                placeholderTextColor="#8b9cb5"
                keyboardType="default"
                ref={durationInputRef}
                onSubmitEditing={() =>
                  descriptionInputRef.current &&
                  descriptionInputRef.current.focus()
                }
                blurOnSubmit={false}
                underlineColorAndroid="#f000"
                returnKeyType="next"
              /> */}
            </View>
            <View style={styles.SectionStyle}>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.accomplishmentTextStyle}
                onChangeText={description => setDescription(description)}
                placeholder="How can I accomplish this goal?"
                placeholderTextColor="#8b9cb5"
                keyboardType="default"
                ref={descriptionInputRef}
                onSubmitEditing={Keyboard.dismiss}
                blurOnSubmit={false}
                underlineColorAndroid="#f000"
                returnKeyType="next"
              />
            </View>
            {errortext != '' ? (
              <Text style={styles.errorTextStyle}>{errortext}</Text>
            ) : null}
          </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};
export default GoalRegistrationScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainBody: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    alignContent: 'center',
  },
  SectionStyle: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginLeft: 35,
    marginRight: 35,
    margin: 10,
  },
  buttonTextStyle: {
    color: '#000000',
    paddingVertical: 10,
    fontSize: 16,
    paddingLeft: 15,
    paddingRight: 15,
    borderRadius: 32,
    borderColor: '#000000',
  },
  inputStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    color: 'black',
    paddingLeft: 15,
    paddingRight: 15,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 30,
    borderColor: '#000000',
  },
  accomplishmentTextStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    color: 'black',
    paddingLeft: 15,
    paddingRight: 15,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 30,
    borderColor: '#000000',
    height: 150,
    textAlignVertical: 'top',
  },
  addButtonStyle: {
    paddingRight: 20,
  },
  linearGradient: {
    borderRadius: 32,
  },
  errorTextStyle: {
    color: 'red',
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 14,
  },
});
```

[image]

Here's an example I had 'testdsdd' in the description and updated to 'test', the onChangeText function should automatically have changed it to 'test', but it didn't. This happens for all states from goalText, descriptionText to setting date.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the `TextInput` `onChangeText` prop to just `onChange` like this:

```js
    onChangeText={ handleInputChange }
```

and then handle the new input in the `handleInputChange`:

```js
    const handleInputChange = useCallback((ev) => {
        const input = ev.nativeEvent.text;

    // you can also do error checking here.

        setDescription(input);
}, [formatMessage]);
```

I always suggest using a pattern like this because it allows you to check for errors or call other methods (like auto-search).

In fact, I suggest using the `handleInputChange` to check for errors and only set the new state for the text-input on an `onEndEditing`.